# Dados dentro do estado estão alterando mesmo sem mandar para alterar diretamente

Tags: react, typescript, checkbox

Atualmente estou com um problema em meu código em que os dados anteriores do estado estão sendo alterados por um novo valor setado para novos dados.

Em resumo, tenho um estado de array permissionsStage que recebe objetos a cada nova interação, cada objeto possui os parametros nmStage e permissions. O problema ocorre nesse segundo parâmetro que é uma interação com alguns checkbox e retorna um array de objetos que dentro possui alguns parâmetros, entre eles o value.

O problema é que a cada interação e mudança dos value's para o último objeto, todos os outros objetos anteriores do permissionsStage também mudam, adicionando ou não um objeto no array.

Foi separado duas tentativas de resoluções em dois arquivos diferentes.
O App.tsx está a primeira tentativa de resolução desse problema, porém sem setar os id´s para cada stage. Já no segundo arquivo, "ChangeWithId", contém os id´s dos stages.

Observação: A mudança visual dos checkboxes não estão mudando mas o valores estão sendo alterados.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-nova-cii2zb?file=/src/App.tsx)

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

interface PermissionsItens {
  id: number;
  label: string;
  value: boolean;
}

interface StageItens {
  nmStage: string;
  permissions: PermissionsItens[];
}

const PRIMARY_STATE_PERMISSIONS: PermissionsItens[] = [
  {
    id: 0,
    label: "Editar documento",
    value: false
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    label: "Fazer upload de documento",
    value: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: "Deletar documento",
    value: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    label: "Reiniciar evento",
    value: false
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    label: "Fazer comentário do documento",
    value: false
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [permissionsCheckboxes, setPermissionsCheckboxes] = useState<
    PermissionsItens[]
  >(PRIMARY_STATE_PERMISSIONS);
  const [stages, setStages] = useState<StageItens[]>([]);
  const [nmStageInput, setNmStageInput] = useState<string>("");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(stages);
  }, [stages]);

  function handleCheckBox(idCheckbox: number) {
    const indexToChangeValueCheck = permissionsCheckboxes.findIndex(
      ({ id }) => id === idCheckbox
    );
    let tempStatePermissions = permissionsCheckboxes;
    tempStatePermissions[indexToChangeValueCheck].value = !tempStatePermissions[
      indexToChangeValueCheck
    ].value;
    setPermissionsCheckboxes(tempStatePermissions);
  }

  function saveStage() {
    setStages((prevState) => [
      ...prevState,
      { nmStage: nmStageInput, permissions: permissionsCheckboxes }
    ]);
  }

  function handleClickButtonSave() {
    saveStage();
    setNmStageInput("");
    setPermissionsCheckboxes(PRIMARY_STATE_PERMISSIONS);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        value={nmStageInput}
        onChange={(e) => setNmStageInput(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Stage name"
      />
      {permissionsCheckboxes.map(({ id, label, value }) => (
        <p key={id}>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={value}
            onChange={(e) => handleCheckBox(id)}
          />
          {label}
        </p>
      ))}
      <button onClick={handleClickButtonSave}>Save</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Amigo, embora o link para onde o código está é útil, seria bom colocar ao menos as partes principais dele em tua pergunta - algo mínimo que reproduza o problema. Isso evita que, caso o link se torne inválido, a questão fique sem possibilidade de compreensão e deixe de ajudar outras pessoas que tenham os mesmos problemas

Comment: Value, cara. Acabei de colocar o código na pergunta.